# i stumbled upon property item does not exist while working on laravel,

Tags: php, laravel

`@foreach($package->items as $item)

  <option value="{{$item->Itemname}}">{{$item->Itemname}}</option>

@endforeach`

but when i do this it fetches the data correctly but it has all the attributes,all i need is the item name,

```
@foreach($package as $item)                 
 <option value="{{$item->items}}">{{$item->items}}</option>             
@endforeach
```

here is my controller code

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
  use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
  use App\Package; 
  class CreatePackageController extends Controller { 
    public function index(){ 
       $package=Package::all(); 
          return view('transactions.create_package',compact('package')); } } 
  class Package extends Model { 
    public function items(){ 
         return $this->hasMany(ItemDoc::class); } } 
  class ItemDoc extends Model { 
    public function packages(){ 
         return $this->belongsTo(Package::class); } }
```

Comment: please format your question - this is illegible

Comment: Please paste in your controller code also.

Comment: @Option i did,in my comments with Alexey

Comment: @Robgogo, sorry but im not sieving through the comment format. Place it in a code block in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pluck()`:

```
@foreach ($package->items->pluck('name') as $name)
    {{ $name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: still the same it is saying property **items** does not exist

Comment: @Robgogo you never said about any error. Please show unfolded result of `dd($package)`

Comment: `Collection {#198 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Package {#199 ▼
   #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "Packagecode" => "123"
        "Packagename" => "test"
        "Packagedesc" => "this is atest"
        "created_at" => "2018-02-22 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2018-02-22 00:00:00"
      ]
      #original: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "Packagecode" => "123"
        "Packagename" => "test"
        "Packagedesc" => "this is atest"
        "created_at" => "2018-02-22 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2018-02-22 00:00:00"
      ]
}`

Comment: @Robgogo so, there is no `items` so, you haven't loaded it. If the original question you've said `$package->items` is working but in the first comment you've said you're getting an error when you do `$package->items`. So which is true?

Comment: there are two tables in my database package and items,and they have a relationship such that a package has many items,and i created a method called items to represent the relationship and to fetch an item associated with a package

Comment: @Robgogo you didn't answer my question. What does `$package->items` returns? An error or collection of items?

Comment: it returns a collection,`foreach ($package as $item) {
      dd($item->items);
     }`,this returns 
` #attributes: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "package_id" => 1
        "Itemcode" => "124"
        "Itemname" => "test item"
        "Itemdesc" => "this is a test item"
        "created_at" => "2018-02-22 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "2018-02-22 00:00:00"
      ]`

Comment: @Robgogo but the code you've shown shows that `$package` is a collection and not an object. And `$item->items` is not a collection, but just one object. Please show all related code including controller method and related relationships.

Comment: `<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Package;

class CreatePackageController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
     $package=Package::all();
     return view('transactions.create_package',compact('package'));
    }
}
class Package extends Model
{
    public function items(){
     return $this->hasMany(ItemDoc::class);
    }
}
class ItemDoc extends Model
{
    public function packages(){
     return $this->belongsTo(Package::class);
    }
}
`